# MLE and confidence interval on Multinomial distribution.

Tags: statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, multinomial-distribution

Let X1,X2,X3, and X4 denote the counts in four cells. Suppose that X1,X2,X3, and X4 follow a multinomial distribution with a total count of n and cell probabilities (2+θ)/4,(1−θ)/4,(1−θ)/4, and θ/4, respectively, where 0 < θ < 1. Given 0 <α<1, find an approximate (1−α)% confidence interval for θ.

This is a past qual question. I tried to find Mle but stuck after finding a quadratic equation in θ. Do we get a nice Mle in this case. Or do I have to find confidence interval without finding MLE and using θ hat instead?

Comment: You can get the MLE straightforwardly enough, I found that it was $\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+8x_4 n}}{2n}$ where $b=x_1-2x_2-2x_3-x_4$. But I don't see how you would easily find the distribution of this in order to use it as a test statistic to define a confidence interval.

Comment: Yes I too got the same result so I am thinking (??) of finding confidence interval just by putting θ hat using the asymptotic property.

Comment: Maybe they expect you to argue that your estimator is asymptotically normal and then construct a confidence interval that is consistent for large enough $n$ that the normal approximation is legitimate. For the MLE I think finding the variance is pretty painful. A blunt way to proceed would be to use $\hat{\theta}=\frac{4}{n} X_4$, at which point you get a binomial problem; I *think* this will be consistent but of course the variance is almost certainly higher than it would be for the MLE. You also don't have $\hat{\theta} \in [0,1]$ guaranteed, which is maybe illegitimate.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the MLE is asymptotically normal and with a whole bunch of tedious calculation you can find its asymptotic variance to get a confidence interval. I'd guess that this is probably what they expected you to do.

Comment: Thank you @Ian.

Comment: One can argue that MLE is asymptotically normal without finding the MLE under some regularity conditions (which hold here); asymptotic variance of MLE can be found from the Fisher information. One can then arrive at a Wald-type confidence interval.